# How to send and store data to rails through jquery/ajax as a JSON object?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

{QUESTION UPDATED}

I want to send some data to the server where rails is installed. My data is in JSON format such as:

```
var JSONObject=  {
             table1: {
                      title: "Title of text",
                      url: "Url of text"
                      }
                  }
```

and I use the following code in cilent:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "http://webadress.com/table1",
            cache: false,
            data: JSONObject,
             statusCode: {

                 200:function() { alert("200"); },
                 202:function() { alert("202"); }
            },
            success: function() {  alert("Data Send!");},
            error: function(xhr){  alert("The error code is: "+xhr.statusText);}        
        });
```

and in the cilent, the following code exists:

```
def create
    @table1= Table1.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url])

respond_to do |format|
  if @table1.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@table1, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @table1, :status => :created, :location => @table1}
    format.json { render :json => @table1}
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json  { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
   end
end
```

But it is not working.
How can I get data and store it in a database. I mean how can I put each element into different columns?

Answer (score 2):

***Best practice***

First of all you should respond to json in the else statement, because if Table1 cannot be saved you are going to get a 406 (Not Acceptable) response code which is inappropriate. 422 (Unprocessable Entity) is appropriate.

```
format.json  { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
```

***Solution***

Then I think the error is in the following statement

```
params[:table1]
```

**1.** If your data are being sent like you said, you can do something like this

```
@table1= Table1.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url])
```

**2.** And if you want to write clean code you should send data this way

```
table1: {
  title: "Title of text",
  url: "Url of text"
}
```

By wrapping your data in table1 you won't need to change anything.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works. Could you validate the answer? Thanks

Comment: Sory Ithought it is going to work but it is not working what could be the problem I did everything as you wrote. But it is not wrking. my code is located in https://github.com/ghaydarov/protonew/blob/master/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

Comment: var JSONObject=  {
 "page": { 
 "title": "Title of text",
 "url": "Url of text",
 "summary": "aaaaa"} 
  }
  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "http://proteomap.tranzsend.com/pages",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: JSONObject,
    statusCode: {
 200:function() { alert("200"); },
 202:function() { alert("202"); } },
          success: function(){
         alert("Working");              
        },
     error: function(xhr){
   alert("The error is: "+xhr.statusText);
 }
});

Comment: However in the follwing adress only an empty data is being created. http://proteomap.tranzsend.com/

Answer (score 1):

As it was a lot of time since the question was asked, I suppose my answer won't help the author but I hope I can help others with similar problem.

I basically replaced this code:

```
@table1= Table1.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url])
```

With this one

```
@table1= Table1.new(params[:table1])
```

Using Firefox with Firebug (to debug the client side/javascript) with this RailCast (To debug RoR) helped me to debug and find an error in my code:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-ruby-revised?view=asciicast

This link may also help:
[Advanced Ajax with RoR and jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579143/advanced-ajax-with-ror-and-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing AJAX POST data as an object wrapped under the key `table1`, you should be able to read the object in your Rails controller's action as `params[:table1]`. You could modify this line:

```
@table1= Table1.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url])
```

to

```
@table1= Table1.new(:title => params[:table1][:title]\
                  , :url => params[:table1][:url])
```

Also, you could add a fail-safe condition in the end to avoid `NoMethodError` should `params[:table1]` be unavailable.

```
@table1= Table1.new(:title => params[:title], :url => params[:url])\
         if params[:table1]
```

and further modify your if condition

```
if @table1.save
```

to

```
if @table and @table1.save
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Can you share any exceptions that you might see in your Rails application log? It would be great if you could paste it at http://pastebin.com and share the link here.