# Advanced Ajax with RoR and jQuery UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I don't have much web development practical experience although I had studied a lot on the web  (Treehouse, CodeSchool, other tutorials and articles).

I have found some explanations on how to use Ajax with RoR and jQuery. But I'm having difficulties to understand how to solve my problem as the explanations often use jquery-ujs that I suppose I can't use in my case.

My problem is difficult to explain here but is similar to implementing [this shopping cart](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart) on RoR, including more parameters like price

The jQuery UI is working for me in my RoR application. What is missing is the AJAX part and how to make it work with RoR

I have found some questions here on StackOverflow that is about this topic but it didn't helped much as they are probably for more advanced users.
So, I believe that the best help would be a tutorial or book or some other reference that is more similar to my problem. However any advice or other kind of directions may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot, finally I solved my problem.

I will post here the resources and some tricks that helped me. I hope it can help others. StackOverflow didn't let me post all the links. For this reason, I just gave some hints that may help to find some resources.

About the jQuery Ajax concepts, I recommend Code School jquery course "The Return Flight".

The second thing that I think helps is learn to debug. Firebug helped me a log to debug the client side/javascript/Ajax. This link may help on that:
http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2642/debugging-tips-how-to-debug-ajax-requests-using-mozilla-firefox-and-firebug

Since the problem may be to debug RoR. Look for a RailCast on the subject.

One of the things that I took some time is if it would be better to use $.ajax(), $.post(), $.get() or $.getJSON(). The link below may explain better but to sum it up, $.ajax() is the more generic one and the other are simpler ones and that call $.ajax() with specific parameters.
[Difference between $.post and $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820074/difference-between-post-and-ajax)

It is important to understand how RoR routing works to call the right url with the right $.ajax() type. "rake routes" may help.

This link may also help to use the right $.ajax() type.
http://old.thoughtsincomputation.com/posts/understanding-rest-in-rails-3

Finally, to send the right format from the javascript to RoR controller, this link may help:
[How to send and store data to rails through jquery/ajax as a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811042/how-to-send-and-store-data-to-rails-through-jquery-ajax-as-a-json-object)